# insert multiple columns to google spread sheet api PYTHON

Tags: python, api, google-sheets-api

I am trying to insert multiple columns to a google Spreadsheet using their api in python, right now I am doing this inside a loop just like this:

```
index = 0
for a in myList:
   sheet.insert_row(a, index) 
   index += 1
```

I would love if i can just send the whole list to the spreadSheet in one call, or anything better than my approach, thanks.

Comment: Not really an answer to your question, but I recently tried the `hyou` ([GitHub](https://github.com/google/hyou/), [PyPi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/hyou/1.2), [Documentation](https://hyou.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)) package from a Google employee and I find it really easy to use.

Comment: hey there thanks, does it support sending all columns in one command ?? if so please point me to the right direction, thank you again.

Comment: The library doesn't make any API requests until you call `commit()`. So you could change the values of the rows and then call commit. See an example [here](https://hyou.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#synopsis).

Comment: this is kind of complex i still need loop to achieve this and call commit every loop.. or can you tell me how you do it ?

Comment: Yes you need a loop, but all changes will be sent in a single `batchUpdate` operation when yo call `Worksheet.commit()`. See my answer for a code example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested in the comments I'll post an example of how to do this with the package [`hyou`](https://github.com/google/hyou):

```
import hyou


my_list = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    [6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
    [11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
]

# Login to Google Spreadsheet with credentials
collection = hyou.login('/path/to/credentails.json')

# Open a spreadsheet by ID
spreadsheet = collection['1ZYeIFccacgHkL0TPfdgXiMfPCuEEWUtbhXvaB9HBDzQ']

# Open a worksheet in a spreadsheet by sheet name
worksheet = spreadsheet['Sheet1']

# Insert values from my_list
for row_index, row in enumerate(my_list):
    for col_index, value in enumerate(row):
        worksheet[row_index][col_index] = value

# Call Worksheet.commit() to apply changes, before this no request will
# be made to the API
worksheet.commit()
```

Also have a look at [views](https://hyou.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#using-views) to read/write to subranges.

Comment: No problem. Go to the spreadsheet in the browser and you can extract it from the URL `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/<spreadsheet_id>/edit#gid=0`. Eg. for `docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZYeIFccacgHkL0TPfdgXiMfPCuEEWUtbhXvaB9HBDzQ/edit#gid=0` the ID is `1ZYeIFccacgHkL0TPfdgXiMfPCuEEWUtbhXvaB9HBDzQ`.